# How to use constants to decode a bitmap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Starting from here:

```
CGBitmapInfo sampleCGImageBitmapInfo =  CGImageGetBitmapInfo(sampleCGImage);
```

How do I use the constants in the defined in the CGImage Reference to determine the byte order use in the image. I want to test against the constants kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little and kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big. I would like to know how to code that. A great answer would be something like:

```
...
NSLog(@"kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big = %___", ____);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it against the constants that are defined with CGBitmapInfo, like so:

```
sampleCGImageBitmapInfo = sampleCGBitmapInfo & kCGBitmapByteOrderMask;
if (sampleCGBitmapInfo == kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault)
{
    NSLog (@"Default byte order.\n");
}
else if (sampleCGBitmapInfo == kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little)
{
    NSLog (@"16 bit little endian\n");
}
else //... etc. for the other CGBitmapByteOrder constants
```

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html) in the "Constants" section for details.